# Filter based on the value of previous elements in the list

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I have a list of objects that looks like this:

```java
class Test {
    String a;
    int sortKey;
}

List<Test> testList;
```

This `testList` is sorted based on `sortKey`.

I want to find the first `Test` object in the `testList` where the value of `a` is `"X"` and the value of all previous `Test` objects in the list till this element is found is `"Y"`

This is what I am trying

```java
testList
    .stream()
    .sorted(sortBasedOnSortKey())
    .filter(test -> test.a().equals("X"))
    .findFirst();
```

How to make sure the previous elements have a value of `a == "Y"`?

Comment: You _can't_ really do this with streams.  Use a normal loop.

Comment: @LouisWasserman this can be done with `Stream::takeWhile`

Comment: Even `takeWhile` can't verify that the elements are all `Y` until the last value is `X`.  You can only check one of those in a single go.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, `takeWhile (X or Y)` and then `filter (X)/dropWhile(Y)` and `findFirst`.  Simple.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the list before the stream.
2. Using `IntStream`, find the index of the first element matching the filter `"X".equals(a)`
3. If such index is found, check that all elements before the index match another filter `"Y".equals(a)`

```java
static Test findFirstAfterAll(String first, String all, List<Test> testList) {
    testList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getSortKey));
    int index = IntStream
            .range(0, testList.size())
            .filter(i -> first.equals(testList.get(i).getA()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(-1);

    return IntStream.range(0, index)
            .allMatch(i -> all.equals(testList.get(i).getA())) 
                ? testList.get(index) : null;
}
```

Test:

```java
List<Test> testList = Arrays.asList(
        new Test("X", 20),
        new Test("Y", 15),
        new Test("Y", 12)
);

System.out.println(findFirstAfterAll("X", "Y", testList));
```

Output:

```
Test(a=X, sortKey=20)
```

---

Using Java 9 `Stream::takeWhile` could work too assuming that *no* element with `a.equals("Y")` may appear before "X":

```java
static Optional<Test> findFirstAfterAll(String first, String all, List<Test> testList) {
    return testList.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getSortKey))
            .takeWhile(t -> all.equals(t.getA()) || first.equals(t.getA()))
            .filter(t -> first.equals(t.getA()))
            .findFirst();
}
```

Tests:

```
System.out.println(findFirstAfterAll("X", "Y", Arrays.asList(new Test("Y", 20), new Test("X", 15), new Test("X", 12))));

System.out.println(findFirstAfterAll("X", "Y", Arrays.asList(new Test("X", 20), new Test("Y", 15), new Test("Y", 12))));

System.out.println(findFirstAfterAll("X", "Y", Arrays.asList(new Test("Y", 20), new Test("Y", 15), new Test("Y", 12))));

System.out.println(findFirstAfterAll("X", "Y", Arrays.asList(new Test("Y", 20), new Test("X", 15), new Test("A", 12))));
```

Output:

```
Optional[Test{a='X', sortKey=12}]
Optional[Test{a='X', sortKey=20}]
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
```

The logic is that only "X" or "Y" may appear in the beginning of the sorted list and as soon as "X" is found it's ok.

---

If at least one "Y" MUST appear before X to make a valid match, similar solution using `takeWhile` can be implemented:

```java
static Optional<Test> findFirstAfterAtLeastOne(String first, String all, List<Test> testList) {
    testList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Test::getSortKey));
    
    int index = (int) IntStream.range(0, testList.size())
        .takeWhile(i -> all.equals(testList.get(i).getA()))
        .count();

    return index == 0 
        ? Optional.empty() 
        : IntStream.range(index, testList.size())
            .takeWhile(i -> first.equals(testList.get(i).getA()))
            .mapToObj(testList::get)
            .findFirst();
}
```

Here the output for the same test data is:

```java
Optional.empty   // no Y before X
Optional[Test{a='X', sortKey=20}]
Optional.empty
Optional.empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can combine `takeWhile` and `dropWhile`:

```java
Test[] tests = {
    new Test("Y", 1),
    new Test("Y", 2),
    new Test("Y", 3),
    new Test("X", 4), // Expecting to yield this value
    new Test("O", 5),
    new Test("X", 6),
    new Test("X", 7)
};
```

```java
Optional<Test> test = Stream.of(tests)
    .takeWhile(t -> t.a().equals("X") || t.a().equals("Y"))
    .dropWhile(t -> t.a().equals("Y"))
    .findFirst();
```